# Efficient way to count the change of values between 2 or more matrix or vectors

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I am checking the change that occurs between different datasets, for now I am using a simple loop that gives me the counts for each change. The datasets are numeric(a sequence of numbers) and I count how many times each change occurs (1 changed to 5 XX times):

```
n=100
tmp1<-sample(1:25, n, replace=T)
tmp2<-sample(1:25, n, replace=T)
values_tmp1=sort(unique(tmp1))
values_tmp2=sort(unique(tmp2))

count=c()
i=1
for (m in 1:length(values_tmp1)){
  for (j in 1:length(values_tmp2)){
    count[i]=length(which(tmp1==values_tmp1[m] & tmp2==values_tmp2[j]))
    i=i+1
  }
}
```

However my data is much bigger with **n = 2000000** , and the loop gets extremely slow.

Can anyone help me improve this calculation?

Comment: For starters, you're using `sort(unique(.))` on 2000000 elements 4 times! One question: What's the maximum value in each of these vectors, are they still 25?

Comment: yes, you can consider that the maximum value is 25.

Comment: Thanks, but your modified code has quite some errors. you may want to correct them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
tmp1 <- c(1:5,3)
tmp2 <- c(1,3,3,1,5,3)

aggregate(tmp1,list(tmp1,tmp2),length)
#   Group.1 Group.2 x
# 1       1       1 1
# 2       4       1 1
# 3       2       3 1
# 4       3       3 2
# 5       5       5 1
```

This might be faster for a big dataset:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(cbind(tmp1,tmp2),key=c("tmp1","tmp2"))
DT[,.N,by=key(DT)]

#    tmp1 tmp2 N
# 1:    1    1 1
# 2:    2    3 1
# 3:    3    3 2
# 4:    4    1 1
# 5:    5    5 1
```